# How to convert user input char to Double C++

Tags: c++, char, double, atof

I'm trying to figure out a method of taking a user input character and converting it to a double. I've tried the `atof` function, though it appears that can only be used with constant characters. Is there a way to do this at all? Heres an idea of what I'd like to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    char input;
    double result;

    cin >> input; 

    result = atof(input);
}
```

Comment: try double result = input;

Comment: What do you means with "it appears" ? Could you elaborate ? A char is only 1 character !

Comment: atof function convert string (array of chars) to double. You need just to do as Ron Tag wrote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`atof` converts a **string**(not a single character) to double. If you want to convert a single character, there are various ways:

- Create a string by appending a null character and convert it to double
- Subtract 48(the ASCII value of '0') from the character
- Use `switch` to check which character it is

Note that the C standard does not guarantee the character codes are in ASCII, therefore, the second method is unportable, through it works on most machines.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of doing it using string streams (btw, you probably want to convert a `std::string` to a `double`, not a single `char`, since you lose precision in the latter case):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::getline(std::cin, str); // read the string
    ss << str; // send it to the string stream

    double x;
    if(ss >> x) // send it to a double, test for correctness
    {
        std::cout << "success, " << " x = " << x << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "error converting " << str << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Or, if your compiler is C++11 compliant, you can use the [std::stod](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) function, that converts a `std::string` into a `double`, like

```
double x = std::stod(str);
```

The latter does basically what the first code snippet does, but it throws an `std::invalid_argument` exception in case it fails the conversion.

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
char input
```

with

```
char *input
```